# Convergence of sequence of rv in distribution and pointwise

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, pointwise-convergence

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)$ and define a sequence of random variables
$$
M_n = \begin{cases}
X,   & n \text{ is even}\\
3-X, & n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
For which values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ do $M_n$ converge in distribution? For these values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, is there a.s. convergence?

Comment: Is the same $X$ used across the board or a sequence $X_n$ is used?

Comment: It is the same X

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Welcome to Math.SE! It would help to know the context where you encountered the question and what you have attempted already.

1. What is the actual distribution of $3-X$?
2. Can you set $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ cleverly so that $X$ and $3-X$ have the same distribution?
3. Now that the same distribution has been achieved, is there a.s. convergence?

Comment: So, first I derived the distribution of 3 - X and I believe it is N ( 3 - u, sigma^2). Then, to set u and sigma^2 I did u = 3 - u, and I got u = 3/2, so that X is N ( 3/2, sigma^2) and 3 - X is N ( 3/2, sigma^2). This way, Mn converges in distribution to X. Then, given that X and 3 - X are both N ( 3/2, sigma^2), I deduced they converge a.s as well. What do you think ? This was an exam I had recently

Comment: @MarcoDiBartolo excellent. Then you have to pick $\mu,\sigma^2$ such that $$\mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right) = \mathcal{N}\left(3-\mu, \sigma^2\right),$$ which values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ work for that?

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering but this really could make my day. What do you think of my reasoning?

Comment: @MarcoDiBartolo you determined $\mu = 3/2$ for any $\sigma^2$ correctly to get convergence in distribution. How do you prove this results in a.s. convergence (I think it does not)?

Comment: Indeed it does not and I lost a point for this...